# External content type from SQL Query

Tags: 2013, external-content-type

Can I create a external content type based on an SQL query?
Can I make an external list based on that content type.

Can I make a list with a lookup column to that new list, and make that field as multiple select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis,

**EXTERNAL CONTENT TYPE WITH SQL QUERY:**
You will need to make a SQL View and for your Read operation, you will use your View instead of the table.. You can easily make **External List with this Content Type**

**LOOKUP COLUMN TO NEW LIST:**
Lookups to External Lists don't allow for multiple values or extended columns unfortunately. Check [Limitations with External List](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/07/bcs-external-list-limitations/)